# Why different results myheritage and ancestry dna give vastly different results when uploaded to gedmatch or illustrative

Tags: autosomal-dna, ancestry.com, gedmatch.com, myheritage.com

Eg.

V2 k15

Myheritage vs ancestry

East med:
39.48 vs 42.99

West asian
19.08 vs 18.73

West Med
16.94 vs 13.79

Red Sea
7.8 vs 8.3

This causes quite an a shift. Eg I go from being cypriot + 13% south Italian to being a cypriot + 30% lebanese druze.

Why such a huge difference?

Comment: The differences that you have in your results are not at all 'vastly different'. Ethnicity estimates from DNA tests are very broad-brush, because they are based on each companies' database of samples from people living today, and how we define 'ethnicity' depends on who you ask. You might find this article from the genetic genealogist helpful: https://dna-explained.com/2018/12/28/ethnicity-is-just-an-estimate-yes-really/